# Favicon Issue in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, favicon

I have an issue regarding the `favicon.ico`

When ever I view the source of the site there is a link for `favicon.ico`

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/images/favicon.ico' />
```

When i click on the href link it does redirect me to right image.
I can't figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Even though it may be obvious, you haven't actually said what you problem is. Presumably the favicon is not showing in the browser tab right?

Comment: can you provide the link to?

Comment: What **is** the problem? You've explained the situation, but not what is going wrong.

Comment: One way to work it is to remove the link in the hmtl and just place `favicon.ico` in the root of your website.

Comment: This may be obvious but worth mentioning. Have you actually tried clearing your browser cache and do a hard reload? And also, does the icon show up in other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried the solution below provided by Macerier?

Comment: Try testing it with another favico file, you can find lots of generic ones via google. Maybe the problem is in the file itself. It happened to me once, the file was corrupt in my case.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please do not advertise or post your own blog/site in your question if that is not part of the question itself as it is regarded as spam and could lead you to a question ban.

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe the browser cant handle "shortcut icon"

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

or if the website is local it wont work in chrome.

Comment: Chrome should handle shortcut icon just fine

Comment: yes it should but in last few mounts i learned to be careful with chrome, it got some crazy small issues in some versions (most of them got solved).